# Popover for a menu in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In order to achieve the behaviour of a popover menu that stays "up" when you move the mouse I used the following script:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
      trigger: "manual",
      animation: false,
      html : true,
      content: function() {
         return $('.popover').html();
      },
      container: 'body'

    })
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () 
        {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
    })

  });

  $(function(){
    $('[rel=popoversturen]').popover({ 
      trigger: "manual",
      animation: false,
      html : true,
      content: function() {
         return $('.popover#sturen').html();
      },
      container: 'body'

    })
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover#sturen").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () 
        {
            if (!$(".popover#sturen:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
    })

  });


</script>
```

But if in the first function everything is okay in my second rel=popoversturen it doesn't stay displayed when you move the mouse on the content.

Below here the html code:

```
<li class="menu">
    <a href="#" rel="popoversturen" data-content="" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover">
        Sturen
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        Ontvangen
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="popover" data-content="" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover">
        Zakelijke oplossingen
    /a>
</li>
```

[image]

I want to be able to go to the links without that the menu disappear.

Here <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ho967wow/1/)</kbd>

Comment: hi i'm confused about what problem is can you show it with jsfiddle or working demo.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara I can't import everything on jsfiddle. In any case If I go on the "popover" menu I can move in the displayed menu without that it disappear (I can click on links if I want).... in the menu with rel: "popoversturen" the menu disappear but the code is the same. Look at it above... I think something is wrong with my syntax.

Comment: bdw you missed to start **<** for on of the **<a>** tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong with the selector.

In the second case I had to use the same selector : #popover for both the calls:  mouseenter and mouseleave functions.

So, the code has changed in this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('[rel=popoversturen]').popover({ 
      trigger: "manual",
      animation: false,
      html : true,
      content: function() {
         return $('.popover#sturen').html();
      },
      container: 'body'

    })
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () 
        {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
    })

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Clicking purpose i have created a single example Please look it out here is the code and below i have given example for working code as well

```js
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html:true,
        content : function() {
             $('#clickGoogle').css({'display':'block'});
             return $('#clickGoogle');
        }        
    });
```

```css
#clickGoogle{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #456334;
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
<div id="clickGoogle" style="display:none;">
<a href="www.google.com">Click For Google </a>
</div>
```

Here i am providing demo working code

[Demo Working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szjf7th6/3/)

Comment: @Silvios please checkout the answer

Comment: it is not correct, I have to achieve the result not with click but with a hover function!

Comment: @SilvioS. let me try on that way

Comment: @SilvioS. hey bdy why don't you write code for the content of that particular elemen's **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** events.??

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: the content is completely included in a html div but It's not the point! It works great for the first one!